# Wait for a saga function completion inside a sagas function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I wanted to wait for the completion of a sagas function which is called inside of another sagas function

i am passing a array of actions like this and then passing it down to `put({type : "SOME_ACTION",payload : {})`
problem is that each of these dispatch calls is dependent on another one so the order is mandatory

`payload.events : [{type : "SOME_ACTION",payload : {},{type : "SOME_ACTION_2",payload : {}]`

```
export function* CHAIN_DISPATCH({ payload }) {
  if (payload.events && payload.events.length !== 0) {
    let index = 0
    while (index <= payload.events.length - 1) {

      const p = payload.events[index]
      yield put(p) // wait here until this call gets completed.. then proceed
      index += 1
    }
    if (payload.callback) yield payload.callback()
    yield put({ type: actions.CHAIN_DISPATCH_END })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would try to think about whether you really need to dispatch the actions. Since actions are essentially events and as such can be listened for by multiple watchers, you are not really supposed to wait for their completion, at least not directly. If you dispatch these actions only to run another saga, perhaps you can instead just run the saga directly?

```
const p = payload.events[index]
// call is blocking so it waits for the saga to finish
yield call(someSaga, p)
```

Even if you need to also update your state in redux, you can perhaps seperate the two:

```
const p = payload.events[index]
// udpate state
yield put(p)
// call saga and wait for it to finish
yield call(someSaga, p)
```

If for some reason you need to stick to dispatching the action then you will need to have some way to inform the original saga that the work is finished. This could be done in multiple ways, one of which is to dispatch another action that will give you the information that the work is finished.

```
const p = payload.events[index]
yield put(p)
// take is blocking so the cycle won't continue until TASK_DONE is dispatched
yield take(TASK_DONE)
```

```
yield takeEvery(SOME_EVENT, function*(event) {
  // do some work
  yield put({type: TASK_DONE})
})
```